# Parcheesi Blockade Rule

Tags: parcheesi

Is moving an existing blockade forward together to form a new blockade on a new space allowed?

Answer (score 3):

**Proposed answer : A new blockade cannot be formed**

Parcheesi is the trademarked name of the American version of the Indian game Pachisi.
*Milton-Bradley* and *Parker Brothers* sold the game under this name and were acquired by *Hasbro*.

The *Parker Brothers* rules do not address the problem presented here.
[Parker Brothers Parcheesi Rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Parchessi.PDF)

The Milton-Bradley rules do explicitly address the situation.

[Milton-Bradley Parcheesi rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/Parcheesi_%282001%29.pdf)

[image: Milton-Bradley rule on blockades]

**Answer**. You are not allowed to form a new blockade from an existing blockade.

Comment: The wiki page also notes that it is prohibited: "Blockade pieces may not be moved forward together with the roll of a double."  (That bit is found with a citation to the Parker Brothers rules, which, as you say, doesn't corroborate the rule.) It was added in a big block of rules text back in April 6, 2015. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parcheesi

(I've added a citation there to the MB rules.)